# Salvar archivo con la hora del sistema utilizando R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando guardar una serie de búsquedas y me gustaría que automáticamente el nombre del archivo csv que genero tuviera la hora. Estoy utilizando `Sys.Date()`, pero esta función escribe solo la fecha DIA/MES/AÑO. ¿Cómo podría especificar también la hora? He probado con `Sys.time()` pero obtengo la misma salida que con `Sys.Date()`.

```
save_as_csv(newTweets, paste0(dirPath, "tweets_2\\", Sys.Date(), ".csv"),
            prepend_ids = TRUE, na = "",
            fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

El objetivo es que cada csv que se salve (incluso dentro del mismo día) tenga un nombre diferente, ya que el proceso de salvado lo tengo automatizado con una tarea CRON.

Cuando utilizo Sys.time obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"), encoding = fileEncoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"), encoding = fileEncoding) :
  cannot open file 'C:\xxxxxxxxxxx\tweets_2\2020-05-30 16:50:49.csv': Invalid argument
```

Comment: La función de `Sys.time()` regresa la fecha incluyendo también la hora ,el formato que utiliza es **Año-Mes-día hora:minuto:segundo zona**  tendría que funcionar correctamente , si quisieras cambiar el formato podrías usar `format()`

Comment: Gracias @RUBEN lopez El caso es que cuando utilizo `Sys.time()` obtengo el error que he publicado en la edición de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que esta marcando es debido a que no te permite utilizar "**:**" y **espacios** dentro de la ruta donde deseas guarda la información, puedes cambiar el formato de la fecha para evitar estos caracteres

```
#Esto nos ayudaria a que la fecha tenga el formato correcto
save_as_csv(rt, paste0(dirPath,"/",format(Sys.time(),"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S"), ".csv"),
        prepend_ids = TRUE, na = "",
        fileEncoding = "UTF-8")

 #El formato de la fecha se mostraría así: 
 format(Sys.time(),"%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
 [1] "30_05_2020_10_29_08"
```